# What is the correct way to send a class in the body of a service with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire, alamofire-request

I am trying to execute this method that I did on android where with the help of retrofit with the `@Body` clause I can send data in the service body, as it is appreciated I do not need to use key - value, I only use `@Body` and the service works perfectly.

```
@POST("/Rest/Login") // <== post
Call<Car> getLogin(@Body Car car); //// **<=== @BODY**
```

but Now I try to do the same in swift using the `JSONEncoding.default` but I don't know how to add my complete class to send in the service since the only way to send is with a key value in a `Parameters` variable. Alamofire's [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md) indicates the same by providing this example which does not work for me.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

Because the service I run does not have a key-value, only the model is sent in the body and that's it. As the example I provide on android using @Body

Comment: Off of the top of my head, I think it’s JSONEncoding().encode(YourCodableClassOrStructName.self)

Comment: I do not understand ? where would that go @Jake

Comment: That should create a dictionary like Parameters that you feed to alamofire

Comment: So if you have a class of `Car: Codable` and it has year, make, model, and serviceRecords. You’ll get the appropriate Json you’d need for the request body by using that function

Comment: And how will I send it in the service? since the variables of the parameters type are key - value..!! Alamofire.request(Constants.ADD_ADDRESS, method: .post, parameters: <#T##Parameters?#>) @Jake

Comment: And how will I send it in the service? since the variables of the parameters type are key - value..!! Alamofire.request(Constants.ADD_ADDRESS, method: .post, parameters: <#T##Parameters?#>)  @Jake

Comment: Cast it ‘as Parameters’

Comment: i can't cast it ! @Jake

Comment: Address' is not convertible to 'Parameters' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')

Comment: If your service accepts key/value POST data rather than JSON then you will need to write some code to put the various properties of your object into a dictionary to send. There is no in-built "convert an object to a dictionary representation" function.

Comment: Sorry I missed a step. After you encode, you get data. If you want a dictionary you need to use JSONSerialization to take the data and turn it into a dictionary